# Angularjs, global Service throwing error

Tags: angularjs

Stuck in a situation, my app is configured in a way, that I have an app controller, which is using ng-route to route between different views and partials, Now from the login controller, I am making a request to get some data, now I want that data to be accessed globally in the application. Now when I create a service, I am injecting it in the app controller module, but I am getting an error service is not defined,

My app.js:

```
var myApp = angular.module('app', ['loginMod', 'dashboardMod', 'newRequestMod', 'ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ngRoute', 'userDetailService']);

myApp .config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider
    .when('/', 
        {
            templateUrl: 'resources/pages/login.html',
            controller:'loginController'
        })
...
```

Now in my logincontroller i am using the service :

```
userDetailShareService.sendData(loginModel);

console.log("Checking the service if it works " + userDetailShareService.getData);
```

userDetailShareService.js:

```
 var app = angular.module('userDetailService',[]);
    app.factory('userDetailShareService', function($timeout,$rootScope) {
        var service = {};
        var dataArray = [];
        service.data = [];

        service.sendData = function(data){
            //dataArray.push(data);

            dataArray=this.data;


        };

        service.getData = function(){
            return dataArray;
        };

        return service;
    });
```

No I am not sure what is throwing that error, the app.js is the first page that is hit, and the data mentioned in login controller is some response data, that I am getting in login controller and then I want to share across my entire application, every controller the data that I get, I do not want to use $rootScope as it will burden the same.

Could anybody please reply, I am in a great need. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you try to reformat your question so that code and actual text are properly formatted? It is pretty hard to read as is...

Comment: You seem to be using `userDetailService` and `userDetailShareService` interchangeably.  Are those supposed to be two separate services?

Comment: Did you inject service in loginController? Show more of controller